# Digital Signage

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, digital

I have been trying to achieve the **Digital Signage**, though Samsung have their **Smart View Sdk** for that. I have tried **Raspberry Pi** but in every case i found the web interface to manage the ad, not the separate chuck of code/ interface so i can embed it with my application.

I am developing android and ios application and i have to create user interaction for signage so one can post to smart tv. But unfortunately i don't know how to /where to start? should i embed the api or some customize-able tool that i can start off.

can you guys suggest me some link/ tutorials for Samsung smart Tv Sdk in app development and for Raspberry Pi, no preference over that.

Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a computer stick with linux openbox a web CMS like wordpress running on localhost modify a theme to take over the whole screen. I developed mine on linux and CMS such as joomla & wordpress with the following functions.

1. Live reload on changes
2. Cloud or remote access via tunnel
3. Remote control the slides via arrow keys also reload, backup, restore and reboot via one click button.
4. Beacon Physical Web with bluetooth.
5. Voice command with google voice api
6. live TV streaming
7. Remote Desktop via google remote
8. Remote connection via bluetooth
9. Schedule slide view base on day, time and hours
   Trust me is better and easier than dealing with the Smart View Sdk.
   Take a look at my system working all open source.
   https://www.youtube.com/user/leoneltvpld/videos

Comment: Hi rijotech. What did you use for live TV streaming? Thanks